# Change Twitter username when logged in via Google?

Tags: twitter

I go to settings - your account - account information - https://twitter.com/settings/your_twitter_data/account

This is where I can typically change account name, when logged in using email and password.

*(I've just checked using my other account and yeah, that's the place where I can update my username)*

But I've created an account via "login with Google" and I feel stuck.

[image]

Any ideas how to update the Twitter username when logged in via Google?

Comment: Have you tried entering your Google pwd here, or trying the `Forgot password?` link?  You need to confirm your password to access those settings.

Comment: "You need to confirm your password to access those settings." - that's the problem. I didn't think about Google password but that's not the practice Google would recommend... I've created a new account, can't be bothered.

Comment: If you initiated the password recovery you would receive a temporary one.  If you disabled SSO your account would revert to a normal one.

Answer (score 0):

Log out of Twitter and click 'Forgot password' to initiate the password reset process. Go through the process and establish a password for your Twitter account. Once this is done, you will have a password to enter when necessary, and you can still login SSO via Google.

Source: I just did this and this was my experience.